# jQuery - Is There Anyway to Abort A List of AJAX Calls Invoked by $.when?

Tags: jquery, asynchronous, promise

In jQuery, I can abort a single async call using the following convention:

```
var xhr = $.ajax(...);
xhr.abort();
```

Is there anyway to abort all AJAX calls initiated using `$.when`?

```
var xhr = $.when(ajaxOne(), ajaxTwo(), ajaxThree());
// Pseudo code
xhr.abort();
```

Comment: No, promises are not cancelable. You'd need access to every XHR object and abort them individually.

Comment: if you store those ajaxOne, ajaxTwo, ajaxThree  ***jQuery* Promises** in some structure, then, you can iterate through that structure and call abort on them as required

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up calling the `abort()` method on each individual promise since there's no built-in way to cancel all requests at once

Answer (score 2):

jQuery ajax calls have their own `.abort()` mechanism.  To use, it you have to keep track of the jqXHR object that is returned from each ajax call.

```
var ajaxCalls = [ajaxOne(), ajaxTwo(), ajaxThree()];
$.when.apply($, ajaxCalls).then(function() {
    // results here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

Then, at some point, you could decide to abort one of the ajaxCalls:

```
ajaxCalls[1].abort();
```

Or, all of them like:

```
ajaxCalls.forEach(function(jqXHR) {
    jqXHR.abort();
});
```

Note that all the ajax requests have already been sent off to the server already and the server is likely already in the middle or processing them.  Calling `.abort()` will keep the client from processing the response, but it will likely not make much of a difference (if any) to the server.

---

The return result from `$.when()` is a summary promise that tracks the results of all the other promises.  You can't call `.abort()` on it to abort the ajax calls.  jQuery simply doesn't work that way.

Comment: @lloydbanks - Did this answer your question?